# What happens when you "and" two lists together?

Tags: python, list

For example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
print(x and y)
```

When I run this, the result is [4, 5, 6]. Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

From the Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

So it will be evaluating `x`, which is not false, then returning `y`.